# Gibbs factor $1/N!$ sometimes yields non-extensive quantities

Tags: statistical-mechanics

The Gibbs factor $\frac{1}{N!}$ in Statistical Mechanics was introduced to correct the fact that entropy was not extensive for a monoatomic ideal gas.

However, in the case of other calculations, this factor makes quantities like entropy and free energy not extensive. For example in the diatomic ideal gas we have

$$
F = -NkT\log(z^{cg}z^{r}z^{v})+kT\log N!
$$

this quantity and the entropy $-\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$ are not extensive. If you do Stirlings approximation for $kT\log N!$  and ignore a term of order $N$ you get

$$
F = -NkT\log(z^{cg}z^{r}z^{v})+NkT\log N
$$

This quantity is extensive (you need to consider what each of the z's are)), but it is in my opinion a horrible approximation and I don't think free energy should be approximately extensive.

As another example, if you are calculating the thermodynamic quantites for $N$ quantum harmonic oscillators textbooks explicitly assume that they are distinguishable in order to get an extensive entropy and free energy.

When are you supposed to use this $1/N!$ factor then? Why is it ignored for the case of $N$ QHOs ?

thanks.

edit: Now that I think of it, its not necessarily a horrible approximation to ignore a term of order N.

Comment: Shouldn't $z^{cg}$ be proportional to the volume of the container? Then, your first expression is extensive.